# Resultado de subtração com double surgem muitas casas decimais

Tags: operadores, dart

estou iniciando em Dart e fui realizar uma operação simples de subtração com `double` porém o resultado fica muito estranho.
Por exemplo em uma subtração de um salário de 3000 menos a teto de inss de 2089,60 o resultado seria 910.40.
Quando faço o `print` aparece 910.4000000000001.

este é o código

```
void main() {
  
  double salMin = 1045.00;
  double vlSalario = 3000.00;
  
  double tetoInss1 = 2089.60;
  double tetoInss2 = 3134.4;
  double tetoInss3 = 6101.06;
  
  double fxCont2 = 1044.59;
  double fxCont3 = 1044.79;
      
  double primFaixa;
  if(vlSalario > salMin && vlSalario <= tetoInss1){
    primFaixa = vlSalario - salMin;
  } else{
    primFaixa = salMin;
  }
  
  double seguFaixa;
  if(vlSalario > tetoInss1 && vlSalario <= tetoInss2){
    seguFaixa = vlSalario - tetoInss1;
  } else if(vlSalario > tetoInss2){
    seguFaixa = fxCont2;
  }
  
  double tercFaixa;
  double quarFaixa;
  
  print(primFaixa);
  print(seguFaixa);
}
```

[image: Erro ao gerar subtração]

Comment: E sua dúvida? Qual é? [EDITA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/458172/edit) a sua pergunta deixando mais claro o que deseja.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String toStringAsFixed(int fractionDigits) 
> Returns a decimal-point string-representation of this.

Retornar uma representação decimal do tipo string, onde `fractionDigits` é a quantidade de casas decimais.

`print(primFaixa.toStringAsFixed(2));`